# Djange NoReverseMatch error - reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django

In a Django app I am building for a course, I am attempting to pass a parameter from one template to a function in views.py through a url path.

The path definition in urls.py contains the parameter name, and the same name is required by the function in views.py.

The link in my template points to the correct url path and names a value for the parameter, but I am still receiving a NoReverseMatch error. Weird because I have another url path that requires a parameter and which is working perfectly.

**entry.html** Here is the link to the path called `edit` in urls.py. I want to pass the value of the variable `entryTitle` to the url as `entry`:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ entryTitle }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ entry|safe }}

    <button>
        <a href="{% url 'edit' entry=entryTitle %}">Edit Entry</a>
    </button>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py** the `edit` path is the last one defined in `urlpatterns`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("new", views.new_page, name="new"),
    path("wiki/edit/<str:entry>", views.edit, name="edit")
]
```

**views.py** This is the edit function, requiring `entry` as an argument UPDATE: also showing the entry function

```
class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(),
        label="Edit Content:")

def edit(request, entry):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Edit file and redirect
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(entry, content)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entry', kwargs={'entry': entry}))
    else:
        #Load form with initial values filled
        content = util.get_entry(entry)
        form = EditPageForm(initial={"content": content})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
           "editform": form,
            "entryTitle": entry
        })

def entry(request, entry):
    markdowner = Markdown()
    entryPage = util.get_entry(entry)
    if entryPage is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/notfound.html", {
            "entryTitle": entry
                      })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdowner.convert(entryPage),
            "entryTitle": entry
        })
```

Clicking the link in entry.html gives me this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /wiki/edit/HTML
Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/edit/(?P<entry>[^/]+)$']
```

If I view page source while on `entry.html` in the server, that link appears to correctly render the path with the correct value for `entryTitle` showing up, which I think means that some communication must be happening between the template and `urls.py`, but then the path isn't found when the link is clicked.

Here is the 'view page source' for entry.html with "HTML" as the value contained by `entryTitle`:

```
<button>
        <a href="/wiki/edit/HTML">Edit Entry</a>
    </button>
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code or have ideas how I could troubleshoot? Been stuck on this one for a few days. Thank you

UPDATE here is the edit.html template:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Edit encyclopedia entry for {{ entryTitle }}</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editform }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
        
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: where is your get absolute_url in models.py?

Comment: Can you please share the entry view. The issue must be there.

Comment: @mehedi, how is this related to get absolute_url? The method is not used.

Comment: @yagus <a href="{% url 'edit' modelname.getabsolute_url_param %}">Edit Entry</a> can be use as geeting the object from url.

Comment: @mehedi, he's using url tag, not get_absolute_url.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls can dig into url docs

Comment: @AB-89v1, your issue is in the `encyclopedia/edit.html` template. Please show it also

Comment: @yagus I posted the entry view and @rvector I included the ```edit.html``` template, it is set up to display the EditPageForm class which I also included in the post under views.py

Comment: Hmm, everything looks fine. Do you maybe have a duplicate path definition in another urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the title as an argument.

````
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Edit encyclopedia entry for {{ entryTitle }}</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'edit' entryTitle %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editform }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
        
{% endblock %}```
````